# from where I download oracle 10g setup file

Tags: oracle

Please tell me where I can download the Oracle 10g setup file and explain the installation procedure of Oracle 10g Express Edition in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index-092322.html

> Oracle Database 10.2 and 11.1 are no longer available for download.
>   The software is available as a media or FTP request for those
>   customers who own a valid Oracle Database product license for any
>   edition. To request access to these releases, follow the instructions
>   in Oracle Support Document 1071023.1 (Requesting Physical Shipment or
>   Download URL for Software Media) from My Oracle Support. NOTE: for
>   Oracle Database 10.2, you should request 10.2.0.1 even if you want to
>   install a later patch set. Once you install 10.2.0.1 you can then
>   apply any 10.2 patch set. Similarly, for 11.1 request 11.1.0.6 which
>   must be applied before installing 11.1.0.7. Patch sets can be
>   downloaded from the Patches and Updates tab on My Oracle Support.

In simple words, this version is not provided any more so to request access to this release, follow the instructions [here](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/ui/km/DocumentDisplay.jspx?id=1071023.1%20).

Comment: Note that the downloads will only be made available for the older releases of 10 and 11 provided you own a valid Oracle Database license (the FULL license), which means if you do not have an Oracle database license, the software is unavailable.